# I NEED TO SUBTRACT TWO VALUES BASED ON TWO COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I need to calculate the balance through them. I got it though, this count depends on two values and is ignoring one value and doing the calculation for all items.

How can I solve?

I need to sum all "QTD_FARDOS" and subtract from "QTD_LANCAMENTO" with the same "NUM_NOTA" and "DES_ITEM", but it's subtracting from everyone with the same "DES_ITEM" regardless "NUM_NOTA".

Here is one case.

[DES_ITEM = 'Pao com Hamburguer 30g' with the NUM_NOTA = "406" has QTD_FARDOS = "1"]

**image [image: 1]**

[DES_ITEM = 'Pao com Hamburguer 30g' with the NUM_NOTA = 406 has QTD_LANCAMENTO = "1.5"]

**image [image: 2]**

[MAKING THE SUBSTRACTION QTD_LANCAMENTO - QTD_FARDOS = 0.5, with the NUM_NOTA = 406, here its right!!]

**image [image: 3]**

[Here is my problem, with different num_nota the result is the same]

**Image [image: 4]**

Here is the query:

```
select
    QTD_LANCAMENTO,
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA,
    DES_PESSOA,
    PRODUTO_CADASTRADO,
    FORNECEDOR_CADASTRADO,
    DES_ITEM,
    UNIDADE,
    CASE WHEN SUM(QTD_FARDOS) IS NULL THEN QTD_LANCAMENTO ELSE QTD_LANCAMENTO - SUM(QTD_FARDOS) END AS SALDO
from NFTemp
left join RecebimentoTemp on NFTemp.DES_ITEM = RecebimentoTemp.ITEM
where
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA = NUM_NOTA (in this case 406)
    and DES_ITEM = DES_ITEM (in this case "Pao Hamburguer 30g")
group by
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA,
    NFTemp.DES_PESSOA,
    NFTemp.PRODUTO_CADASTRADO,
    NFTemp.FORNECEDOR_CADASTRADO,
    NFTemp.DES_ITEM,
    NFTemp.UNIDADE,
    NFTemp.QTD_LANCAMENTO
```

Can anyone help me? If the NUM_NOTA is different than 406, for example, 380, SALDO needs to return QTD_LANCAMENTO = 1.5

Thank you!

Edit: I'm picking 380 from NFTemp table, that contains all itens with QTD_LANCAMENTO [Here all that contains NUM_NOTA = 380](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MUcE.png)
[Here all that contains NUM_NOTA = 406](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T59bd.png)

Comment: Where are you taking that 380 from?

Comment: @banana_99 I added a edit, thank you since now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure on what your data model is, but could you give this a try and let me know?

```
SELECT
    num_nota,
    des_item,
    SUM(qtd_lancamento - qtd_fardos) diff_sub
FROM
    yourtable        a
    LEFT JOIN yourothertable   b ON b.column = a.column
GROUP BY
    num_nota,
    des_item
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of left join you need inner join to avoid unwanted rows.

```
select
    QTD_LANCAMENTO,
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA,
    DES_PESSOA,
    PRODUTO_CADASTRADO,
    FORNECEDOR_CADASTRADO,
    DES_ITEM,
    UNIDADE,
    CASE WHEN SUM(QTD_FARDOS) IS NULL THEN QTD_LANCAMENTO ELSE QTD_LANCAMENTO - SUM(QTD_FARDOS) END AS SALDO
from NFTemp
inner join RecebimentoTemp on NFTemp.DES_ITEM = RecebimentoTemp.ITEM
where
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA = NUM_NOTA (in this case 406)
    and DES_ITEM = DES_ITEM (in this case "Pao Hamburguer 30g")
group by
    NFTemp.NUM_NOTA,
    NFTemp.DES_PESSOA,
    NFTemp.PRODUTO_CADASTRADO,
    NFTemp.FORNECEDOR_CADASTRADO,
    NFTemp.DES_ITEM,
    NFTemp.UNIDADE,
    NFTemp.QTD_LANCAMENTO
```